# Vite - React - App keeps refreshing with log: Server connection lost polling for restart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, vue.js, vite

Issue : Suddenly app keeps refreshing indefinitely giving this log in console: `server connection lost polling for restart.`

#### Steps to Reproduce

- run the application in docker
- Running vite with the --host flag via the shared url: `https://192.168.1.xxx:3000`

#### System Info

System:
OS: macOS 11.4
CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Memory: 808.27 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 14.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.5 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.14.13 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Browsers:
Brave Browser: 91.1.26.74
Chrome: 91.0.4472.114
Firefox: 88.0.1
Safari: 14.1.1

Vite : 3.0.0

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig, ConfigEnv } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig((_configEnv: ConfigEnv) => {
    return {
        server: {
            port: 3000,
            strictPort: true,
            hmr: {
                 protocol: 'ws',
                 host: 'localhost'
            },
        },
        base: './'    
    }
});
```

Comment: This happens when the HMR port is not accessible from the client. See [`vite-setup-catalogue`](https://github.com/sapphi-red/vite-setup-catalogue) for example Docker setups, which might help determine the problem on your end.

Comment: okay will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me, changing 'port' to 'Port'

```
server:{
    hmr: {
        host: 'localhost',
        Port: 8011,
    },
},
```